# How do I then see that $\mathcal I \setminus (\mathcal E = \{f(x) = 0 : x \in \mathcal I \})$ is an open set?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f: \mathcal I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a **continuous** function from an open interval $\mathcal I$ to the real numbers $\mathbb R$.

How do I then see that $\mathcal I  \setminus (\mathcal E = \{f(x) = 0 : x \in \mathcal I \})$ is an open set ?

I see that $\mathcal I \setminus \mathcal E = \mathcal I \cap \mathcal E^C = f^{-1}(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})$ and $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ is an open set. Does this mean that the preimage of $f$ is open ? I also know that the intersection of two open sets are open.

Comment: If $f$ is assumed to be continuous the answer is yes because the pre image of an open set by a continuous function is open

Comment: You miss an assumption about continuity, I believe.

Comment: You are right, the function is continuous. Can you link to a proof ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a continuous function, then $f^{-1}(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})$ is open due to the definition of continuous functions: “A function $f:\rightarrow Y$ is open, if every preimage $f^{-1}(A)$ is continuous for $A \subseteq Y$ open“

If $f$ is not continuous, then $f^{-1}(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\})$ does not need to be open. Take $$f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R: x \mapsto \begin{cases} 0 & ; x \ge 1 \\ 1&; x < 1\end{cases}$$ Then $f^{-1}(\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}) = [1, \infty)$.

Comment: Can you link to a proof ? Is this a consequence of what theorem ?

Comment: And a function can't be "open" :P

Comment: It's the definition of continuity in topology. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces (and thanks, I corrected my answer... ;-) )